# Counting 2 Columns from Separate Tables Between 2 Dates

Tags: sqlite

I have a query that Counts 2 columns from 2 separate tables using subqueries, which works. Now I have to implement into this query the ability to filter out these results based on the Date of a Call Record. I will post the query in which I am working with:

```
SELECT (m.FirstName || " " || m.LastName) AS Members,
   (
       SELECT count(CallToLineOfficers.MemberID) 
         FROM CallToLineOfficers
        WHERE CallToLineOfficers.MemberID = m.MemberID
   )
+  (
       SELECT count(CallToMembers.MemberID) 
         FROM CallToMembers
        WHERE CallToMembers.MemberID = m.MemberID
   ) AS Tally
FROM Members AS m, Call, CallToMembers, CallToLineOfficers
Join Call on CallToMembers.CallID = Call.CallID
and CallToLineOfficers.CallID = Call.CallI
WHERE m.FirstName <> 'None'
-- and Call.Date between '2017-03-21' and '2017-03-22'
GROUP BY m.MemberID
ORDER BY m.LastName ASC;
```

Ok, so table Call stores the Date and its PK is CallID. Both CallToLineOfficers and CallToMembers are Bridge Tables that also contain only CallID and MemberID. With the current query, where the Date is commented out, that Date range should only return all names, but a count of 1 should appear under 1 person's name.

I have tried joining Call.CallID with both Bridge Tables' CallIDs without any luck, though I think this is the right way to do it. Could someone help point me in the right direction? I am lost. (I tried explaining this the best I could, so if you need more info, let me know.)

UPDATED: Here is a screenshot of what I am getting:

[image: Count]

Based on the provided date in the sample, the new results, with the Date, should be:

```
Bob Clark - 1
Rob Catalano - 1
Matt Butler - 1
Danielle Davidson - 1
Jerry Chuska - 1
Tom Cramer - 1

Everyone else should be 0.
```

Comment: Sample data and the desired result would be helpful. Anyway, it looks as if you forgot to join the `m` and `Call` tables.

Comment: Originally I had them in there, but couldn't seem to figure out if they were correct. I'll readd them and provide a screenshot of what I get and what I should get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the subqueries filter only on the member ID. So for any member ID in the outer query, they return the full count.

To reduce the count, you have to filter in the subqueries:

```
SELECT (FirstName || " " || LastName) AS Members,
   (
       SELECT count(*)
         FROM CallToLineOfficers
         JOIN Call USING (CallID)
        WHERE MemberID = m.MemberID
          AND Date BETWEEN '2017-03-21' AND '2017-03-22'
   )
+  (
       SELECT count(*)
         FROM CallToMembers
         JOIN Call USING (CallID)
        WHERE MemberID = m.MemberID
          AND Date BETWEEN '2017-03-21' AND '2017-03-22'
   ) AS Tally
FROM Members AS m
WHERE FirstName <> 'None'
ORDER BY LastName ASC;
```

Comment: Is "USING (CallID)" another way to say Call.CallID = CallToMembers.CallID? I have not seen USING before.

Comment: Yes, it's the same (but also removes the duplicate column from the result).

Comment: That's great. I wish I would've learned that 8 months ago haha. I also took your advice from the last question you answered of mine and decided that subqueries would be best here.